# centering the default TextField hint - MaterialUI

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I was getting started with [material UI](https://material-ui.com/api/text-field/) and was trying to get the `TextField` component to behave the way I wanted. The animation that it gives by default is cool, yet, I wanted it to align it to the center, yet it sticks to the top left:

[image]

I want the `Email Address` hint that is in the `TextField` outline to be positioned like that in the center of the top outline. How do I do that?

Comment: Can you share with us, your try or add a codesanbox with the example ?

Comment: @gionic , sure, but, All I did was just use the properties mentioned in the docs, because that's all I'm capable at the moment, and there's not a explicit value to change this there

Answer (score 1):

you can pass a style Object in the `inputProps` like this:
 `<TextField inputProps={{style:{textAlign:"center"}}} id="outlined-basic" label="Outlined" variant="outlined" />`
here [sandBox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-0e3sm?file=/demo.js)

Comment: that's centering only the cursor, not the `Email Address` that sticks on the outline of the TextInput box. I had already centered the cursor, (in my question above)